# Google Maps API markers not appearing when I change data source

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

======================================================================

## Further Update

It seems I may not have been clear enough in my initial attempt to ask this question, so I'm going to try again.

I have two files.  One works.  One doesn't.  The only difference is the xml source.
http://hplconsortium.com/web/wtcd/WTCDlisting/GoogleMapsWithMultipleMarkers_working.html 
http://hplconsortium.com/web/wtcd/WTCDlisting/GoogleMapsWithMultipleMarkers.html

What could possibly be the reason why changing the location of the xml file (which as far as I can tell is the exact same file, just in two different locations) would make the markers disappear?
I've checked, and xml is being served correctly on the server.

================================

## Original Posting

I have tried everything that I can think of to solve this problem and have spent many hours perusing the questions and answers, but I can't figure this one out. I'm completely new to Google Maps API and this is my first attempt, so it could be something stupid and simple that I'm just missing.  I hope someone can help me.

I started out using the sample code from Google Maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)

It works just fine when I use the code as-in on my website.  However, when I try to change the locations to my own list, the markers do not appear.  I tracked down the problem to something having to do with the actual location of the source because when I try to move the xml file from it's stored location:
 https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml

to my own website folder, even though I haven't changed a single other thing the markers disappear.

My investigation led me to something about data layers, and I'm wondering if I have to store my own list somewhere special in order for this particular code to work.  If not, then how can I customize this code so that it works with my list?

The sample code xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <markers>
    <marker id="1" name="Billy Kwong" address="1/28 Macleay Street, Elizabeth Bay, NSW" lat="-33.869843" lng="-151.225769" type="restaurant" />
    <marker id="2" name="Love.Fish" address="580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" type="restaurant" />
    <marker id="3" name="Young Henrys" address="76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW" lat="-33.898113" lng="151.174469" type="bar" />
    <marker id="4" name="Hunter Gatherer" address="Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW" lat="-33.840282" lng="151.207474" type="bar" />
    <marker id="5" name="The Potting Shed" address="7A, 2 Huntley Street, Alexandria, NSW" lat="-33.910751" lng="151.194168" type="bar" />
    <marker id="6" name="Nomad" address="16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.879917" lng="151.210449" type="bar" />
    <marker id="7" name="Three Blue Ducks" address="43 Macpherson Street, Bronte, NSW" lat="-33.906357" lng="151.263763" type="restaurant" />
    <marker id="8" name="Single Origin Roasters" address="60-64 Reservoir Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.881123" lng="151.209656" type="restaurant" />
    <marker id="9" name="Red Lantern" address="60 Riley Street, Darlinghurst, NSW" lat="-33.874737" lng="151.215530" type="restaurant" />
  </markers>
```

My own data I'm trying to get it to use is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <markers>
    <marker id="1" name="CJ Rhoads of Kutztown University" address="15200 Kutztown Road, Kutztown PA USA" lat="40.5173" lng="-75.7774" type="restaurant" />
    <marker id="2"  name="Diane Gold, Corporate Tai Chi"  address="Boca Raton, FL 33432, USA" lat="26.3402" lng="-80.0814" type="bar"  />
    <marker id="3"  name="Tai Chi - Stress Management and Relaxation Technology"  address="10100 Roe Ave, Overland Park, KS 66207, USA" lat="38.9453" lng="-94.6394" type="bar"  />
  </markers>
```

(Later I'm going to try and change the restaurant (R) and bar (B) to event (E) and school (S), but first I just want to get it running with the original markers.)

Can anyone help me?  What am I missing?

Comment: Is your server configured to serve XML with the correct MIME type?

Comment: Well, I looked in the control panel under MIME types, and it appears that it should be configured properly.  I found the line:
'application/xml xml xsl'
which would seem to me that the server is properly configured.  I'm using godaddy Linux Deluxe hosting.  Is there any way I can check that it is actually serving the file as an xml file?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Thank you, mkyong.  I looked at that tip and used it, and verified that the xml file is being served appropriately.  Anyone have any thoughts on what I can try next?

Comment: I appear to have gotten a -2 at the top.  Is that a downvote?  I read all the help documents on how to ask a good question and thought I followed all the guidelines.  Can someone explain why my post would be downgraded and how I can improve it?  Apologies for being such a newbie. 
P.S. I would gladly hire someone to help me if you know someone who could do so.

Comment: @C.Sham - you used a similar example when you asked about the embed a URL link under the marker.  Would you be willing to help me with this question?

Comment: The link that "doesn't work" displays this javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null`.  The XML parser doesn't think it is valid XML.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip.  However - I was able to get it to work by changing the name and using the original name in the sample file.  Perhaps you can explain why, when you change the name (but the contents of the file is exactly the same) the parser thinks that it is not valid XML.  I can't explain it, but now that I have a working file, I'm happy.  Here is the link to the working file:
[link]http://hplconsortium.com/web/wtcd/Events.html

Answer (score 0):

Ahah!!!  I found the answer.
It was not the location of the file that was the problem, it was simply the name of the file.  When I copied the file from the google storage area to my own server, I also changed the name from mapmarkers2.xml to mapmarker.xml - and that was causing the markers to disappear.
Obviously, somewhere in the example code is a requirement for the datafile to be named exactly mapmarkers2.xml and it cannot be changed (without knowing where else in the file that name appears, of course, which I haven't found).

Thank you all for your help and support. 
Peace
CJ Rhoads